# How to retrieve n number of previous and after lines in log file using logstash configuration?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am creating an application where I need to put previous and after n number of lines in elasticsearch with current log. This is my current logstash configuraion.
What changes I need to make so that I can retrieve last n number of lines(Let's say 5) in my output?

```
input{ file{ path => "D:\ELK_Info\TestLogs_Updated.log"
#start_position => beginning
    ignore_older => 0
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
        codec => multiline {
                               pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
                               negate => true
                               what => "previous"
        } } }

filter{
    grok{
       match => {
      "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{DATA:line_number} %{DATA:log_level} %{DATA:log_type} %{NOTSPACE:space} %{GREEDYDATA:stackTrace}"    }   }   mutate { remove_field => [ "tags", "space", "line_number"]} }

output { file{ path => "D:\ELK_Info\logstashOutput.log" }
```

Comment: You want to read last 5 lines from the input file and send it to your output file ?

Comment: need to read last 5 lines from a complete log inside "message" key retrieved in the filter(yes, from input file)

Comment: @ben5556 Let's say, I have a log inserted in a file just now. So while inserting that into my output file/elasticsearch DB, I also need to insert last 5 lines from that log. Because developers may have some information there which will be useful to find root of the error.